# RegionPlot of ImplicitRegion is incorrect

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, bugs, computational-geometry, regions

**Bug fixed in 10.4.**

Why does `RegionPlot` of the `ImplicitRegion` give an incorrect plot? Also, will how does this affect calculations with `ImplicitRegion` (i.e. if the plot is incorrect are calculations using it also incorrect)?

```
RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[x^3 <= y <= x^2, {{x, 0, 1}, y}]]
```

gives,

[image]

When it should give this,

```
Plot[{x^2, x^3}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Blue, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

I think it is not reliable as look at what it does in `Plot3D`

```
Plot3D[x + y, {x, y} \[Element] ImplicitRegion[x^3 <= y <= x^2, {{x, 0, 1}, y}]]
```

[image]

When expecting this,

```
Plot3D[x + y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^3 <= y <= x^2 \[And] 0 <= x <= 1],
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Am I doing it wrong or is this a bug?

---

The `ImplicitRegion` plots work in 10.2 Win 7 Pro 64bit but not in 10.3 Win 7 Pro 64bit.  Can others confirm this is a 10.3 bug?

---

Confirmed "*regression in our Region functionality*" from WRI for version 10.3 with [CASE:3485986].

Comment: What version are you using?  I get this:  http://i.imgur.com/iDwQaYM.png , using version 10.2 Linux

Comment: 10.3 Win 7 Pro 64bit

Comment: Odd, I get the first plot3d to work as well,  http://i.imgur.com/0ouRoCS.png

Comment: I just tried in 10.2 and it works. I think it is a 10.3 bug.

Comment: Weird, backwards progress - should rename the post to something more informative like "Plotting with ImplicitRegion works better in version 10.2 than in 10.3"

Comment: With 10.1 I get a plot thats not *quite* as bad, but still not right (both ends are truncated).

Comment: 10.2 does it perfectly without the need for the `PlotPoints` option. Looks like it was off in 10.1, fixed in 10.2, and then seriously broken in 10.3 Sounds like a job for [Regression testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing) :-(

Comment: Interesting workaround:   `RegionPlot[ ImplicitRegion[x^3 <= y <= x^2 && (0 <= x^2 <= 1), {{x, 0, 1}, y}]]`   and   `Plot3D[x + y, {x, y} \[Element] ImplicitRegion[x^3 <= y <= x^2 && (0 <= x^2 <= 1), {{x, 0, 1}, y}]]`

Answer (score 4):

To your second question ...does it affect calculations?

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[x^3 <= y <= x^2 && 0 <= x <= 1, {x, y}]
RegionBounds@reg
{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}

{Area@reg, Integrate[x^2 - x^3, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]}
{1/12, 1/12}
```

**addendum**

```
{g = RegionPlot[reg], greg = DiscretizeGraphics[g]}
```

[image]

```
{Area@greg, Area@reg // N}
{0.034617, 0.0833333}
```

Care must be taken. It remains an uneasy feeling.

Answer (score 3):

This is a comment with graphics rather than an answer:

Interestingly, I think that the problem may lie in `ImplicitRegion`, rather than in `RegionPlot`. Notice that `RegionPlot` works fine with the predicate definition of the region itself:

```
RegionPlot[x^3 <= y <= x^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 120]
```

[image: regionplot result]

On the other hand, `DiscretizeRegion` shows the same problem with your `ImplicitRegion` definition:

```
DiscretizeRegion[
  ImplicitRegion[x^3 <= y <= x^2, {{x, 0, 1}, y}],
  Frame -> True
]
```

[image: discretizeregion]

Comment: This is definitely the case.  In version 10.2, I get the expected result for the `DiscretizedRegion`