# Possible bug with RegionPlot

Tags: plotting, bugs, regions

```
RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[(2 x - 1)/(x - 1) < 3/2, {x, y}], 
 PlotRange -> {{-9, 9}, {-9, 9}}]
```

[image]

Just checking whether anyone else can replicate this.
Can anybody confirm such behavior and, maybe, confirm this as a bug?

Comment: Same result with Linux 11.0.1

Comment: It does not work on `10.4.1` too. The following inequalities also do not work: `1/x < 1` and `1/x <-1`.

Comment: Yes, I think that's a bug and it would be good if you could report it.

Comment: The bug is still present in `11.1.0`

Answer (score 9):

Another thing to do is just cut `ImplicitRegion` out of the loop altogether.  `RegionPlot` is naturally designed to take a predicate of inequalities.

```
RegionPlot[(2 x - 1)/(x - 1) < 3/2, {x, -9, 9}, {y, -9, 9}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There have been [other](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98073/9490) [examples](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101813/9490) of `RegionPlot` having trouble with `ImplicitRegion`, and usually the answer is just to give the inequalities to `RegionPlot` directly.

Comment: much simpler (and natural) +1. Hope WA is going well

Answer (score 8):

This can worked around by using [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html),e.g:

```
p = Plot[(2 x - 1)/(x - 1), {x, -5, 5}, 
   GridLines -> {{-1, 1}, {3/2, {2, Red}}}, PlotRange -> {-5, 5}, 
   Frame -> True];
rp = RegionPlot[
   ImplicitRegion[Reduce[(2 x - 1)/(x - 1) < 3/2, x], {x, y}], 
   PlotRange -> {{-9, 9}, {-9, 9}}, PlotStyle -> {Pink, Opacity[0.2]}];
Show[p, rp]
```

[image]